# Norm of finite flat morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be two schemes and $f : X \to Y$ be a finite flat map. In the following document http://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~t-saito/talk/eepr.pdf page 20, the author talks about the norm map  $$f_* : f_*\mathbf{G}_{m,X} \to \mathbf{G}_{m,Y}.$$ He then says that this induces a pusch-forward of $\mathbf{G}_{m}$-torsors and a map $Pic(X) \to Pic(Y)$.

How does one define the norm map that he talks about ?

When he says that this defines a push-forward of $\mathbf{G}_{m}$-torsors is just by using the norm map locally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I assume $Y$ noetherian and connected or some other hypotheses so that things work well or this is in fact your question? Then take a look to Lemma 30.14.5. in the Stacks Project: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BCX

Comment: ah that's very interesting thank you. In fact by finite flat I think the author meant finite locally free so your refence works well. Still I don't see wether it's the same thing the author of the reference I gave meant ? I also saw the definition of $N_f(\mathcal{L}) = \Lambda^d(f_* \mathcal{L})$ (where $d = deg(f)$) is that the same thing too ?

Comment: You mean at the level of Pic? The definition in that Lemma in Stacks Project is locally the determinant (of multiplication by the element) so it should be the same than the definition with the top exterior power.

Comment: No I mean what is the relation with the norm map for G_m ?

Comment: The norm is multiplicative.

Comment: OK I need to think about the details a bit more but I think I see how it works. Thank you very much.